# Need help recursively creating a directory tree using the Boost Property Tree library and XML

Tags: c++, xml, recursion, boost

I've created an XML file that represents a directory layout for a project. It looks like this:

```
<folder>
    <folder>
        <name>src</name>
        <file>
            <name>main.cpp</name>
        </file>
    </folder>
    <file>
        <name>Makefile</name>
    </file>
    <file>
        <name>README.md</name>
    </file>
</folder>
```

I'm using the Boost property tree (`boost::property_tree::ptree`) to parse, represent, and create the directory (the program I'm trying to write is a command line tool that generates empty C++ projects). I'm trying to write a function that will create the directory recursively, but I've never used this library before, am currently running into a few mental blocks, and feel like I'm going about it all wrong. If anyone has used this library before and can give me a few pointers with my code, I'd appreciate it. Here's what I have so far:

```
static void create_directory_tree(std::string &root_name,
    boost::property_tree::ptree &directory_tree)
{
    // Create the root folder.
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(root_name);

    for (auto &tree_value : directory_tree.get_child("folder"))
    {
        // If the child is a file, create an empty file with the
        // name attribute.
        if (tree_value.first == "file")
        {
            std::ofstream file(tree_value.second.get<std::string>("name"));
            file << std::flush;
            file.close();
        }

        // If the child is a folder, call this function again with
        // the folder as the root. I don't understand the data
        // structure enough to know how to access this for my
        // second parameter.
        else if (tree_value.first == "folder")
        {
            create_directory_tree(tree_value.second.get<std::string>("name"), /* ??? */)
        }

        // If it's not a file or folder, something's wrong with the XML file.
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All of your if statements try to assign a string to another `=`, I assume you want to compare it `==` ?

Comment: Oops. Well, that's embarrassing... Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me what you're asking.

I hope my take on it helps:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56b622c922860373)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::property_tree;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

namespace project_definition {
    void apply(ptree const& def, fs::path const& rootFolder) {
        for (auto node : def) {
            if ("folder" == node.first) {
                fs::path where = rootFolder / node.second.get<std::string>("name");
                fs::create_directories(where);

                apply(node.second, where);
            }
            if ("file" == node.first) {
                std::ofstream((rootFolder / node.second.get<std::string>("name")).native(), std::ios::trunc);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ptree projdef;
    read_xml("input.txt", projdef);

    try {
        project_definition::apply(projdef, "./rootfolder/");
    } catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

With a `input.txt` of

```
<folder>
    <name>project</name>
    <folder>
        <name>src</name>
        <file><name>main.cpp</name></file>
    </folder>
    <file><name>Makefile</name></file>
    <file><name>README.md</name></file>
</folder>
```

Creates a structure:

```
./rootfolder
./rootfolder/project
./rootfolder/project/README.md
./rootfolder/project/src
./rootfolder/project/src/main.cpp
./rootfolder/project/Makefile
```

Comment: You understood perfectly. Sorry about any ambiguity; I wasn't entirely certain about what I was -supposed- to want in terms of using this library. What you gave is extremely close to what I was wanting. I greatly appreciate the example code.